# Page specific menus in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to make a page specific menu in Wordpress, where each page has its own options... The link is http://dev.activenation.co.uk/leisure-centre/southampton-water-activities-centre/

As you go through the "Your Centre" pages, the grey menu changes. At the moment, we are using conditional if statements to load the specific menus, however, the client will need to add more leisure centres.

Was just wondering if there was a more time saving way of doing page specific menus, instead of coding conditional if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a custom meta box to the 'page' content type that is a simple `<SELECT>` list of all of the custom WordPress menus. On save, pull the selected menu ID from the `SELECT` list and save it to the database. On the page template, check if the saved value exists and if it does, pull in the WordPress menu that has the saved ID.

This will allow an editor to create any number of menus, pick a specific one for each page, and share like menus between pages.

There are a lot of tutorials and code snippets around creating custom meta boxes, and displaying a simple `select` of the available menus. If you haven't done custom meta boxes before, this is a good intro project since it only has one form field and it's easy to validate the data.

Smashing Magazine has a great walk through on custom meta boxes: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/04/create-custom-post-meta-boxes-wordpress/

Comment: Thanks for the idea! Didn't think of this. Put a custom meta box on the pages, and made it look for a menu in the Wordpress menus section. Then I created all my menus in there. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If those Centres are subpages of "Your Centre" you could try to use [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hierarchical-pages/) which creates hierarchical pages / category / taxonomy lists.